# Qt Scroll area can't scroll

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

I have a problem with QScrollArea, I want to make a scrollable design, because standard window is not enough for me. But, I can't scroll it down and add / see new content. I don't know why. I want to set for eg. 1600 px scroll area height and make a layout to it in Desiner. But in this situation I can't scroll it:

[image: Egzample]

I heard a tip to add a layout to ScrollArea, but I don't want to use it, I want to make a layout myself.
I have tried to uncheck 'widgetResizable'

So is it any other method to scroll this widget?

Comment: Show us the structure. We can't see what is inside what from the information you've provided. It seems that you have set the scroll area's widget, and you've put some other widgets inside that widget, but the scroll area's widget is still the same size as the scroll area.

Comment: Yes you're right, I want to place in scroll area a lot of small widgets like buttons, pictures and plain texts. I want to get a chance to place a widget blow the down edge of scroll area, then scroll down and edit it / add more widgets. But in proveded case I can't scroll down.

Comment: Nothing is clear without the code. I can only assume that scroll area has no clue of the 'real' scroll widget size: in Qt the widget in scroll area won't scroll until its size set to the content it supposed to hold. I do it like:     m_pScrollWidget->resize(m_pScrollWidget->sizeHint());